# Use a disk image for Link2SD's 2nd partition

Tags: internal-storage, file-system, link2sd

Well, this question is targeted for those few devices without support for an external SD card as well as merged storage, for example my Micromax Canvas Knight A350.

I thought this up today:

If we take a QEMU disk image file (.img), set it to static with a size for, say, 4GB and format it to `ext2` and copy it over to the Android device's internal SD card, can we mount it as `/mnt/sdcard2` or something similar as a `loop device` (it appears that `loop device` mounting is possible on stock Android 4.0.4 and up, at least for some Samsung devices)?

Secondly, will this work with Link2SD?

Context: My device, as mentioned above, has a 2GB `/data` partition which is fast running out. I thought this up as a last-ditch effort to extend its lifespan (because it has 25GB `/sdcard0` partition`, and I don't use more than 12GB of it), and would like to get the theory of this validated or refuted before I go about trying this on my device.

**NOTE:**

Any alternative suggestions, such as [FolderMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.fmount&hl=en) (kindly suggested by @Izzy in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android-enthusiasts)), are also welcome if these are accompanied with **proper usage instructions** for this specific case, that is, link folders from `/data` to internal SD.

Side Note: Not currently considering FolderMount as it's advertised for internal SD to external SD linking, not `/data` to internal SD linking.